# Running serverside php and apache could I tell the browser to show another URL in the adress bar without redirecting&reloading and without javascript?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, metadata, address-bar

So the user could click one of a lot of fields, and the browser will then look for the url 
`http://example.com/result?x=967&y=105&action=show`

Using current php and apache serverside and delivering the content of the page could I tell the browser to show in its adress bar instead
`http://example.com/result_x_967_y_105_action_show.html`
**without redirecting&reloading and without javascript**?
(One goal: The user could easily save a bookmark or save the html-page, as the browser already uses or suggests as filename `result_x_967_y_105_action_show.html`?)

Something like php-header information, apache modules or html-meta tags in the delivered html-file?

And are there pitfalls like the browser then always looking for 
`result_x_967_y_105_action_show.html`
even if the parameters of a subsequent pagecall have changed to something else like 
`http://example.com/result?x=123&y=223&action=run`